# Python: Find contain text using Xpath with a list

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a list of text snippets to identify within a website, using Selenium and `find_element_by_xpath()`. So far I am able to find a specific word:

```
greeting = ['Hi', 'Hey', 'Hello']

for greeting in greet_list:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="Chat"]/span[text()="{greeting}"]'):
```

So far I have tried and some other methods by no success:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="Chat"] and [contains("{greeting}")]')
browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="Chat"]/span[Contains[text()="{greeting}"]]')
```

Thank you so much in advance! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here `greeting = ['Hi', 'Hey', 'Hello']` `greeting` is a list. You can not iterate it like this :

```
for greeting in greet_list:
```

it has to be :

```
for greet in greeting:
```

you can have any name in place of `greet` .

Also I do see that you have `:` at the end of `browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="Chat"]/span[text()="{greeting}"]'):` which is wrong.

**Trial :**

```
for greet in greeting:
    ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[@id='Chat']/span[text()='{greet}']")
```

this should work for most cases. Also `ele` is a web element. so you can do stuff like `.text`, `.send_keys` etc on that. Remember you are not performing any action so it's all guesses that we have.

if this does not work, you can debug like this :

```
//*[@id='Chat']/span[text()='Hi']
```

copy the above `xpath` and see in `HTML DOM` that you have desired matching `nodes`. Also if there are `multiple nodes`, remember `find_element` will only take the first matching node.